# ASP.NET MVC3 dropdown JQuery change event wire up gone wrong

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to wire up and change event jQuery handler for a dropdown list I have to populate a div "payment" with html returned from my controller action as soon as user changes a value in the dropdown.

Here is what I have so far and I have no idea why it's not working or on how to chase this further.  No errors or response from changing the dropdown value.  Any help very much appreciated!

cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PaymentType").change(function () {
        var selection = $("#PaymentType").val();
        var dataToSend = {
            paymentType: selection
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "Order/PaymentChanged",
            type: "GET",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#payment").text("server returned:" + data.agent);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div id = "payment">
   <br />
   @Html.Label("Select payment method")
   <br />
   <select id="PaymentType" name="PaymentType">
     <option value="CreditCard">Credit Card</option>
     <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
     <option value="Check">Check</option>
   </select>
   </div>
 }
```

OrderController.cs

```
    public JsonResult PaymentChanged(string paymentType)
    {
        return Json(new { agent = "sample html" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Standard, largely unchanged _Layout.cshtml file with all jQuery src including src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint inside the change event function to see if it is being hit? From what I see this should work. Also why are you using such an old version of jquery?

Comment: @Kadajski He's probably using a default MVC project which comes with 1.5.1 unless he's upgraded lately or is using Nuget.

Comment: Why did you write `<select...` html yourself instead of using a MVC helper method?

Comment: @Kadajski I have tried setting a break point and it is not getting hit.  I am using the default MVC project as TerryR suggests. I can update, but figured this functionality should be covered by 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks fine to me so I'll answer "how to chase this further"

- Use [Chrome's debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the [status of your XHR](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html).
- Run your MVC app in Debug mode (from Visual Studio) and put a break point inside your controller to see if it's actually being called and if `paymentType` is being sent properly (the former is more likely given your code looks fine).

Comment: I have tried setting a break point in both the script and the controller, no luck with either one. I will try using the Chrome debugger as I haven't tried that.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, looking closer through the chrome debugger, I noticed that there were 404's being generated.  From the info I gathered that my routing was incorrect.  I removed the "Order" from url: "Order/PaymentChanged" and all worked as expected. Thanks for sending me down the right path.

Comment: Figured that was the problem.  Just as an aside, you should take a look at absolute vs. relative URL paths and make sure you understand *why* you needed to remove "Order".  Cause just as an FYI, if you use that same code on a global script and call it from another controller it won't work.